# How to send mail with text of different colors from Unix using command 'mail'?

Tags: email, unix, colors

I would like to send message from Unix server. I use command 'mail':

```
echo "MESSAGE_BODY" | mail -s "MESSAGE_TITLE" somebody@gmail.com
```

It's ok with it.
After that I want to send message with different colors. I tried this command:

```
echo "<font color="red">MESSAGE_BODY</font>" | mail -s "MESSAGE_TITLE" somebody@gmail.com
```

But it didn't help me. How to use colors ?

Answer (score 1):

There have already been a "one-liner" that have posted the correct answer.
I do still feel that it's better to post how and why.

The reason why you can't just echo HTML code directly into your mail is that the receiver (Client) don't know how to display it. So it will most likely just fallback to clear text and all you would see was your HTML code when viewing the message.

What you need, is to tell the client that the content of your message is composed in HTML. You do this by adding the correct MIME header to the message.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Notice you can also set charset information.

The MIME version is there for better compatibility also some SMTP servers will give you a higher spam score if you don't obey the RFC :)

But with these headers set now all "BODY" content will be treated like HTML content.

I don't just want to provide you with a "one-liner" I think showing more in a script is better to make it easier to read.

**So how about this**

```
(
echo "From: my@email.tld";
echo "To: some@email.tld";
echo "Subject: Test html mail";
echo "Content-Type: text/html";
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
echo "";
echo "<strong>Testing</strong><br><font color=\"blue\">I'm Blue :)</font>";
) | sendmail -t
```

Well technically it's still a one-liner :) But it just looks nicer and you can see what's going on!

**Bonus information**

If you want to have both HTML and TEXT bodies you need to look into Multipart content type bodies. I have included an example but you would properly need to read up on this if you don't know much about multipart types.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--0001boundary text--"

--0001boundary text--
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

The TEXT body goes here

--0001boundary text--
 Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<strong>HTML code goes here</strong>
--0001boundary text--
```

As you can see it's no longer some simple mail body.
But I thought I wanted to show you how it was done in case you wanted to give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<font color="green">Message body</font>" | mail -s "$(echo -e "Message title\nContent-Type: text/html")" somebody@gmail.com
```

Comment: While your answer might be the solution, it is always appreciated to have further information to get better understanding and gain insights.